# When does patent US5807360 expire?

Tags: expiration

In reference to the patent: [US5807360](https://www.google.com/patents/US5807360)

Answer (score 0):

This is a utility patent and has 20-year patent term. Counted from its filing date is September 27,1996, so this patent would be expired on September 27, 2016.